# Redirect specific domain on Bind DNS server

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system

I am running a DNS server which is used by remote computers (only specific IP addresses are allowed). I wish to block a few domains by redirecting them to a request form that is hosted on another server. So for example, if a machine makes a request to `example.com` then I want it to be redirected to `anothersite.com`.

As mentioned above, the request form is hosted on a website that sits on an external server and not on the same DNS server network. Also just for full clarity, my DNS server is currently just acting as a forwarder. I would like to keep it as a forwarder but just be able to handle a few domains that do not get forwarded.

Is this something that can be done on the DNS server?

Answer (score 2):

DNS has no concept of "redirect", this term comes from HTTP.

You can apply filtering and rewrites in DNS servers, to force some policies. This is typically called a "DNS firewall" but has to be used with caution as the DNS level might not be the most appropriate ones (clients can bypass DNS either by using DOH to connect to outside nameservers not implementing your policies, but they can as well directly used IP addresses fetched somehow and hence not having to do name resolutions; in short: be clear on what you are trying to achieve and all the circumvent cases that exist)

It depends on which nameserver you use. For `bind` it is called RPZ for "Response-Policy Zone" and is documented at https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.19/doc/arm/html/chapter6.html#dns-firewalls-and-response-policy-zones

In the description below, note the 3rd point that should pertain to your case:

> A response policy action can be one of the following:
>
> - to synthesize a “domain does not exist” (NXDOMAIN) response
> - to synthesize a “name exists but there are no records of the requested type” (NODATA) response
> - to replace/override the response’s data with specific data (provided within the response policy zone)
> - to exempt the response from further policy processing

But the response of a name/A or name/AAAA query is a set of IP addresses, which is what you will need to override. Be aware though that there could be `CNAME` records involved.

Comment: Thanks, this certainly seems useful. Is there an example or tutorial for the type of use case that I have?

Comment: Your use case seems similar to the one described at https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-00520

Comment: I follow that example and then restart my DNS server but when testing it, nothing happens

Comment: Do you think this could be because my DNS server is set up to be a forwarder?